# function/command to retrieve web content (besides from wget or file_get_contents)

Tags: php, http

I need to retrieve a web content. I usually use wget but it's giving me an "Internal Server Error" this time. I also tried using file_get_contents(), it works when I'm using MAMP installed in my Mac, but when I run it in our server, it's not doing anything and prints no error message. Is there any other way to do this? Below are the code that I used.

```
<?php
echo "Retrieving Traffic Updates";
$source = file_get_contents('http://www4.honolulu.gov/hpdtraffic/MainPrograms/frmMain.asp?sSearch=All+Incidents&sSort=I_tTimeCreate');
echo $source;
?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

---

I don't know how to reply to all of you so I just added it here. CURL WORKED PERFECTLY. Thanks a lot guys. 
I just have to ask though why file_get_contents() won't work even if it's enabled in the php.ini?

Comment: Well, you use a period instead of a semicolon on line 4. Is this your *exact* code sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
<?php 
echo "Retrieving Traffic Updates";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www4.honolulu.gov/hpdtraffic/MainPrograms/frmMain.asp?sSearch=All+Incidents&sSort=I_tTimeCreate"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$source = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);      
echo $source
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you don't have the `fopen` wrappers enabled.  To test, do:

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

If this returns `false` (or `0`, can't remember which), you can't use `file_get_contents` to open a remote file.

If [`cURL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is installed, you can use that to access remote files.

Comment: I ran the code and it returns: string(1) "1". I guessing it's enable but I'll try curl if that one would work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`allow_url_fopen` may be turned off by your web host. You should see if this can be turned on. If not, [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) may still available so you should try using that instead.

Answer (score 1):

If cURL is available to you, use that. You can determine if cURL is installed by doing a `phpinfo();`. For more information on cURL: [PHP: cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

Please reference http://davidwalsh.name/download-urls-content-php-curl for a solid example of using PHP's implementation of CURL to fetch the contents located at a given URL.

I believe you'll find the process fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

$html = curl("http://www4.honolulu.gov/hpdtraffic/MainPrograms/frmMain.asp?sSearch=All+Incidents&sSort=I_tTimeCreate");